# How can i secure a web application in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, security, hash, cryptography

Guy in the major videos I have seen storing in the database hashed passwords. And that's ok. But if I want to encrypt them too? Using for example  SHA512 with RSA512. But there is a difference between Hash and then Encrypt and vice versa? I use Node Js/Mongoose and express.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack , you should use bcrypt package with mongoose , `bcrypt.hash` and `bcrypt.compare` … with salt rounds 8 to 10:

Comment: I know that, but i want to secure more and more my web application. Other to hash algorithms...

Comment: coulyou elaborate ?

Comment: use hashed Cookies for safe post requests

Comment: i use *jwt* most of the time

Comment: SIMPLY: SHA512 + RSA > SHA512?? Can they be used together???

Answer (score 0):

Hashing and encryption are two different concepts, the main difference being that a hash is a one way algorithm and encryption is bi-directional. You should never encrypt passwords because there's no valid reason to decrypt them.

You could encrypt the salted hashes if you felt like it, the necessity of it is questionable if you have a solid salted hash scheme in place. If you want to go that route the term you're looking for is "Encryption at Rest", you can google it in relation to mongoose.

At the end of the day, you should be getting your passwords over TLS, so they come to you encrypted and then you decrypt them because you need the plain text of it to make the hash for storage. You don't gain anything by then encrypting it again either before the hash or after the hash. In fact, you're just adding computational work to slow down your server and introducing the liability of how you're handling your private key.

Additionally, SHA+RSA isn't an encryption scheme, it's a signature scheme. You hash with SHA and sign with your private key so anyone who has your public key can verify that the hash is valid and comes from you.

Comment: So if I hash the password and then encrypt it, will be useless because add useless computational work? But with this signature scheme, the password will be more secure right?

Comment: No, using a public key signature is for an entirely different use case where you are giving something to a third party and you want them to be able to verify both it's integrity (via the hash) and it's authenticity (using your public key to verify that it hasn't changed since you hashed it).